# What is the best way to store project's images while using Github

Tags: image, github, project

I'm wondering what is the best way to store project's images while I'm using Github

If I'm storing images on Github the repo becomes giant and hard to clone.
I would use CDN to store images but the architecture looks a bit weird, since I can't have the images in the git repo, and it's stored outside.

What would be the best way to store the project's images along with the code?

Comment: Did you already check out Git LSF on Github? https://git-lfs.github.com/